# Autenticar usuario (Facebook) con Firebase

Tags: swift, swift2, facebook, firebase, oauth

Estoy intentando autenticar a mis usuarios registrados por medio de Facebook en Firebase. Pero la documentacion de Firebase esta en objective-C y estoy trabajando con Swift.

Ya he creado la app desde facebook y activado en el dashboard de Firebase la autenticacion por facebook.

Ya tengo la parte de autenticacion con Facebook, el siguiente fragmento de codigo extraido de la documentacion de Firebase:

> To log a user in, we'll need to retrieve the OAuth Access Token from
>   Facebook. Once we have the access token, we can use
>   authWithOAuthProvider:token:withCompletionBlock: to authenticate the
>   user with Firebase. Below is one way to get an access token with read
>   permissions from the Facebook SDK.

En español medio traducido dice asi:

> Para registrar un usuario , tendremos que recuperar el acceso OAuth
>   simbólico de Facebook. Una vez que tenemos el token de acceso, podemos
>   utilizar authWithOAuthProvider:token:withCompletionBlock:  para
>   autenticar al usuario con Firebase. A continuación se muestra una
>   forma de obtener un token de acceso con permisos de lectura desde el
>   SDK de Facebook.

```
class LoginViewControllerMaster: UIViewController{

    var ref: Firebase!
    //var loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    @IBAction func LoginFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {

        ref = Firebase(url: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com/")
        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

        facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_birthday"], fromViewController : self , handler: {
            (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in

            if facebookError != nil {
                print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
            } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
                print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
            } else {
                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                self.ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
                    withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Login failed. \(error)")
                        } else {
                            print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                        }
                })
            }
        })

    }

    @IBAction func LogoutFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {
//        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
//        loginManager.logOut() // this is an instance function
        print("Voy de salida")


    }
}
```

Hasta aqui todo va perfecto. Del codigo anterior la parte clave segun entiendo esta aqui:

```
let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                self.ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
                    withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Login failed. \(error)")
                        } else {
                            print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                        }
                })
```

Sin embargo, de aqui ya no veo que camino seguir para lograr loguear mis usuarios en Firebase. Hay muchos ejemplos en la web de como loguearse con usuario y password, pero de redes sociales casi nada.

Agradezco de antemano su amable apoyo.

Comment: Me faltaba hacer lo siguiente, pero sigo en las mismas. :( Add Firebase as a Valid OAuth Redirect URI by adding the URL: https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback in the Facebook Advanced tab under Settings in Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

He seguido buscando  y he llegado a la siguiente solucion. Es probable que pueda optimizarlo y mejorarlo pero de momento ya ha funcionado. Espero a alguien le sirva.

```
@IBAction func LoginFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {

ref = Firebase(url: "https://Myapp.firebaseio.com/")
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_birthday"], fromViewController : self , handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in

    if facebookError != nil {
        print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
    } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
        print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
    } else {


        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
        self.ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
            withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Login failed. \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                    print ("Access Token \(accessToken)")
                    //INICIA PROCESO DE RECUPERACION DE CAMPOS
                    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,interested_in,gender,birthday,email,age_range,name,picture.width(480).height(480)"])
                    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                        if ((error) != nil)
                        {
                            // Process error
                            print("Error: \(error)")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //print("fetched user: \(result)")
                            let id : NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as! String
                            print("User ID is: \(id)")
                            let correo : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! String
                            print("EL Correo es \(correo))")
                            //etc...
                            // INICIA CREACION Y AUTENTICACION DE USUARIO EN FIREBASE
                            // 1
                            self.ref.createUser(correo as String, password: String(authData)) { (error: NSError!) in
                                // 2

                                if error == nil {
                                    // 3

                                    self.ref.authUser(accessToken, password: String(authData),
                                        withCompletionBlock: { (error, auth) -> Void in
                                            print("Creado")
                                            // 4
                                    })
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    print("hay errores. \(error)")
                                }
                            }
                            //TERMINA CREACION Y AUTENTICACION DE USUARIO EN FIREBASE
                        }
                    })
                    //TERMINA PROCESO DE RECUPERACION DE CAMPOS

                                            }
        })
    }
})

}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias hermano! dale click en el check verde para colaborar a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D